# cron does not work

Tags: cron

I read about [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto). I edited it by running `crontab -e` and I added this line:
 
`* * * * * php /var/www/createFile.php`
When I run `ls /tmp/` I do not see any file create by my php script. Why does not it work ?

when I run `php /var/www/createFile.php` it works fine, however (the effect is the creation of a text file in `/tmp/`
I changed the command to:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/createFile.php > /tmp/createFile.log 2>&1
```

As [Jos](https://askubuntu.com/users/149708/jos) suggested me below. When I run `cat /tmp/createFile.log` I get this:

```
python can not open file 'createfile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I used the full path to **createfile.py** as Jos suggested me in **createFile.php** now I get this error:

```
sh: nmap not found
0sh: nmap not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that scripts called by `cron`, as well as subsequent scripts called by them, use full paths to the files referenced. Scripts that run perfectly well when run by the owner, but fail when executed by `cron`, nearly always have such a reference error.

Also, in order to find out why `cron` jobs fail, look at the syslog; if the `cron` job needs to write output to `sysout`, it will try to mail it to the user if `sysout` has not been redirected. Same goes for `syserr`.